# Exception: '<' is an invalid start of a value Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Have a problem with receiving data from api using service. Can someone help? Is the problem in receiving html data instead json, but don't know why, tried to make desearialization but doesn't work.
Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

    public ItemController(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetItems()
    {
        return Ok(await _appDbContext.Items.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class ItemService : IItemService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ItemService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();

    public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems()
    {
        Items = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>("api/item");
        return Items;
    }
}
```

BaseClass:

```
public class ItemsBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IItemService ItemService { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await ItemService.GetItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code "should have worked". Any changes to the startup code in Client or Server?

Comment: @HenkHolterman in startup on client side I added the service   builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<IItemService, ItemService>(); and on server side I added srvice for db context builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Items_Management")));

Comment: And that is all

Comment: Still, as the answers below show, we are missing some detail...

Comment: Your code is small and close to a [mre]. The service plays no part here, so: create a new scratch project, add a Controller and a Page and try again. You can skip the Db as well, just return a fixed List<> .

Comment: And another check: Does the FetchData page still work?

Comment: solved, by creating new project and rewriting the controller, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow on from @Surinders answer:

1. Put a breakpoint on this line and check that the API is getting hit, and then what is being returned.

```
   Items = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>("api/item");
```

2. Use Postman to check what you are getting back from the Url.  Postman is a great tool for debugging API's.  Search "Postman API".

Comment: calling api directly I get the json file, calling page get the error of html file

Comment: @Matt Brown, I guess if you've accepted this answer, you've found the issue with your code, right. Please, let us know what was the issue, and how you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your API, instead of returning  List its returning error in the form of html, which starts with <

So debug your API endpoint and see where the error is occurring