# '<' is an invalid start of a value (Blazor)

Tags: c#, razor, controller, blazor

In my Create.razor page where I create a blog, I set the URL, create a new blog post, and navigate to its page:

```
async Task CreateNewBlogPost()
    {
        newBlogPost.Url = $"{newBlogPost.Chars}/{newBlogPost.Title.Replace(" ", "-")}";
        var result = await BlogService.CreateNewBlogPost(newBlogPost);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"{newBlogPost.Chars}/{newBlogPost.Title.Replace(" ", "-")}");
    }
```

This razor page opens: @page "/{char}/{title}"
Within it, it runs this:

```
[Parameter]
    public string Char { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        string url = $"/{Char}/{Title}";
        CurrentPost = await BlogService.GetBlogPostByUrl(url);
    }
```

I know it's a little overkill to constantly be recreating the URL but I've been experiencing navigation problems in the past when not using Char and Title directly. It then calls `GetBlogPostByUrl()` which is this:

```
public async Task<BlogPost> GetBlogPostByUrl(string url)
        {
            //var post = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<BlogPost>($"api/Blog/{url}");
            //return post;

            var result = await _http.GetAsync($"api/Blog/{url}");
            if (result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                return new BlogPost { Title = message };
            }
            else
            {
                return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<BlogPost>();
            }
        }
```

However, I then proceed to get this error in the console:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

I've used breakpoints to test the different values and everything seems to be good. The URL is good, the else command is ran which means it's 200OK, and the blogpost is created within the SQLite database. I'm a little stuck on why it is giving me this error. I definitely think it's the `readfromjsonasync(blogpost)` but I don't know where to tackle it. Thanks.

My app is a Blazor Web Assembly with ASP.NET hosted, so I have all Client, Server, and Shared side. I can give my blog controller if needed. Thanks again.

Comment: My wild guess would be that the controller does not return json but a page. What happens when you start the app open a new tab and call `...api/Blog/{url}` directly in the browser ? Do you get json or html ?

Comment: This question is answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159489/exception-is-an-invalid-start-of-a-value-blazor-webassembly/71160048#71160048

Comment: This has been asked a lot, and you didn't post the Controller. Most likely: your URL doesn't match your route.

Comment: @SurinderSingh - that Q+A is very unhelpful.

Comment: I ended up just setting it to - between char and title, since in the end I'm gonna be changing it from identifying through URL to searching through database (because quicker). I'm taking note of using ...api/Blog/{url} in the browser though when I create one, right now when I do it after opening it says Post does not exist which is good. And thanks for that referral, clears up a lot of stuff.

Comment: @HH Ya likely is, I ended up jumping through a hoop but I'll probably encounter it again so I'll look into that thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
 string url = $"/{Char}/{Title}";
```

combined with

```
var result = await _http.GetAsync($"api/Blog/{url}");
```

Will call an URL with `api/Blog//{Char}/{Title}`

That double **`//`** is your main problem.